# Standard C++ Parallelism using nvc++ is slow

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, nvidia

I am not sure what i am doing wrong but it seems `std::sort` is much slower using `nvc++ -stdpar` than `g++`.
Other std functions are better but never better than the multithreaded CPU version.

Below is the code where TIMEIT is just a macro to compute the before and after timer.

```
using Duration = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>;
std::random_device rd;
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(1,1000);

int main(){

int n=1<<21;
std::vector<float> v(n);

std::generate(v.begin(),v.end(),[&](){ return dist(rd);});
Duration d;
TIMEIT(d,
std::sort(std::execution::par,v.begin(),v.end());
)
std::cout<<d.count()<<"\n";
```

The results are

`nvc++ -stdpar std.cu`  217.164

`g++ -O2 std.cpp -ltbb`  69.9

Note that **nvc++** issues a warning about a sequential run for cc less than 70 but
when i try without -stdpar the time is 756 so i am guessing that it is parallelizing.
If not, i am not sure how to force it to parallelize.

```
nvc++ 22.3 on WSL2 on Windows 11

GPU: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti with Max-Q Design, 6GB RAM

CPU: Intel I7-1065G7, 32 GB RAM
```

Comment: @user17732522 You are right. I actually used g++ -O2 std.cpp -ltbb

Comment: It doesn't matter on nvc++

Comment: Ok, I was just making sure that there is no obvious issue with the question. (Missing optimization flags are surprisingly often the answer to such questions here.)

Comment: Does it make sense to try `nvc++ -O2`?

Comment: @alfC I would assume that it does since nvc++ supposedly hands-off the non-GPU code to be compiled to g++ or clang. But i tried it with and without -O2 and it gives  more or less the same running time.

Comment: @HikmatFarhat, given the history of nvc++ probably that is delegated to a PGI-like EDG-frontend compiler, not gcc.

Comment: It looks like `-stdpar` means *offloading* to the GPU. Naive offloading is notoriously bad for `< O(N²)` algorithms (like sort) as copying is not negligible. Form https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerating-standard-c-with-gpus-using-stdpar/ "An NVC++ command-line option, -stdpar, is used to enable GPU-accelerated C++ Parallel Algorithms. ... GPU acceleration of C++ Parallel Algorithms is enabled with the -stdpar command-line option to NVC++. If -stdpar is specified, almost all algorithms that use a parallel execution policy are compiled for offloading to run in parallel on an NVIDIA GPU".

Comment: Honestly I don't understand the philosophy of NVC++ -stdpar, if it is going to offload all operation blindly it is probably a bad idea to use `par` except for very specific algorithms. Since most STD algorithms are `< O(N²)` I don't understand the utility unless one is dealing with very heavy element types or costly numerics.

Comment: This isn't CUDA code.  This is not the CUDA compiler, and `nvc++` is not part of the CUDA toolkit.  Please remove the `cuda`  tag.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Ok done. Is nvidia tag ok?

Comment: yes, `nvc++` is provided by NVIDIA

Answer (score 0):

**Standard C++ parallelism using nvc++ is NOT slow at all**

I see two issues with your test:

1. Your hardware does not seem appropriate (your GPU is not exactly great).
2. The test is not performed correctly. You should remove the time required to transfer data from the host to the GPU.

But, of course, a lot depends on the hardware. I just happen to sit on a more appropriate hardware for such a comparison.

```
CPU: two Intel Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz.(44 physical cores and 64 GB RAM)

GPU: just one NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti (8 GB)
```

The compilers are

```
nvc++ 23.1-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux

g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
```

Both are great compilers (in my humble opinion).

For clarity, I post the full code below so that everyone can reproduce it exactly as I intended.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <execution>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>

std::random_device rd;
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(1,1000);

int main(){

    int n=1<<21;
    std::vector<float> v(n);

    std::generate(v.begin(),v.end(),[&](){ return dist(rd);});

    {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::sort(std::execution::par,v.begin(),v.end());
            
        auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
        std::cout <<  "Time elapsed: " <<  duration.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;
    }

    return 1;
 }
```

My results are

```
nvc++ -stdpar=multicore std.cpp : 84962 microseconds
```

```
g++ -O2 std.cpp -ltbb : 17130 microseconds
```

```
nvc++ -stdpar=gpu std.cpp : 3824 microseconds
```

Therefore nvc++ wins hands down when I run the code on my GPU, but loses to g++ when in multicore. This is a trend I observed in many other projects: the GNU compiler is better than the NVIDIA one (basically PGI) for multicore. But it is also possible that they are just using resources differently. Long story short, GPU wins here.

**And GPU wins even when at a disadvantage**. Just out of curiosity, let's add a line just after std::generate

```
std::for_each(std::execution::par,v.begin(),v.end(),[](auto& it) { it *= 2.;});
```

We are not counting this for_each in the time elapsed. We just use it to move our memory from the host to the GPU, so that when we call std::sort on the GPU, the memory is already there and does not need to be copied (magic of the unified memory management). In this way, we just count the time required by the GPU to run the sorting algorithm.

The result is

```
nvc++ -stdpar=gpu std.cpp : 650 microseconds (memory already there)
```

So, nvc++ standard parallelism on GPU is around 28 times faster than g++ parallelism on multicore (which is better than nvc++ multicore).